# Looking to record a macro in word, but picture options aren't available

Tags: vba, ms-word

Currently trying to build a macro in word so that I can simply select a picture I've pasted in the document, then click on the macro so that it sets the layout option of the selected picture to square, and the distance from text below it to 0.1". However, the record macro button doesn't allow me to select a picture, nor can I figure out how to build it from scratch as I don't even know where to start. Any help to get my on my way would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Try selecting the picture before starting the macro recorder. If the picture is inline with text, you should be able to click an insertion point beside the picture. Then use the keyboard arrow keys with the Shift key to select the picture. In VBA, start with the _Selection_ object, then add methods or properties that are relevant to pictures.

Comment: Currently trying to do this myself and having the same issue as OP. Starting to Record a macro clears any image selection, and prevents me from selecting any images while recording. As soon as I stop recording I can select images again.